# split: regex to ignore delimiters inside balanced parenthesis

Tags: sql, regex, perl

I've got ORDER BY part of the statement and I have to split it at logical parts

```
my $sql_part = <<EOH
    IF(some_table.some_field <> 3, 1, 0), 
    some_table.other_field, 
    CASE other_table.third_field WHEN IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
    other_table.third_field
EOH
```

and, you know, original string doesn't contain newlines and IF's can be nested.

The problem is I don't want to split the stuff inside the nested IF's, function calls.

So simple `split /\s*,\s*/, $sql_part` won't work.

Is there a regex that can do this, or should I do it just differently?

Answer (score 3):

There is a regex, but you probably want to just use an SQL Parser: [SQL::Statement](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/SQL::Statement::Structure)

Comment: For the benefit of search engines: when a specialised parser as in the given answer is of no use, [`Data::Record`](http://p3rl.org/Data::Record) will do the job.